# REGEX: How to filter special character between brackets?

Tags: regex

Im trying to find correct regex code, which fill match special character (") between brackets, e.g. `[ "-11.268390225228275, 14.952959610966833]`,`[-21.02888891289231, 14.952959610966833" ]`. I need to match only " character.

I have already tried this code `(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])`, but It will match me only all characters between brackets, not only " charaters.

Please, does anybody know how to match only " characters between brackets?

Comment: Your data format looks strange. Why is there a quote inside the brackets? Why is there no quote in the middle of the line? Could you describe your problem without mentioning regular expressions? What do you want to achieve in the end? I'm asking because regular expressions are not a solution to any real-life problem, they are only a small tool for solving part of a problem.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/krM1cI/2 for engines that support `\G` and `\K` (PCRE and the like).

Comment: A .NET regex will look like `(?<=\[[^][]*)"(?=[^][]*])`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%29%22%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29&i=%22+%5b+%22-11.268390225228275%2c+14.952959610966833%5d%0d%0a%5b-21.02888891289231%2c+14.952959610966833%22+%5d+%22). If you are coding in a full fledged programming language, you may even do what you need with the expression you already have (if, as I assume, you want to remove/replace all `"`s inside `[...]`). What is the programming language? Please share your current code.

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew, I code it in FME by Safe software, I use StringReplacer transformer and I need to remove " character, because I need to export JSON with coordinates. But, coordinates number cannot be closed by " character.

Comment: So, it is using PCRE, right? Jan's solution should work. `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]["]*\K"` and replace with empty. (I just removed non-greedy quantifier after including `"` into the negated character class for better performance)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect, thank You so much! It works, I couldnt uderstand how to compose the code. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a PCRE regex like

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]["]*\K"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/krM1cI/3)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A)`  - the end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^]["]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `"` - a double quotation mark.